# Unknown error XNA cannot detect importer for "program.cs"

Tags: xna, c#

I am not too sure what I have done to cause this, but even after undoing all my edits, this error still appears

> Error 1   Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "Program.cs".
>   There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project. 
>   (filepath)\Advanced Pong\AdvancedPongContent\Program.cs   Advanced Pong

After receiving this error, everything between #if and #endif in the program.cs fades grey

```
using System;

namespace Advanced_Pong
{
#if WINDOWS || XBOX
static class Program
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Game1 game = new Game1())
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
 }
#endif
}
```

I have searched this and could not find a solution anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is something for stackoverflow. It's not gamedev related. offtopic though: might I ask why you are checking if it's for xbox or windows...I mean if it's not, your program would never run anyways.

Comment: this is what XNA produces every time. I haven't touched anything in the program.cs file

Comment: Is the Program.cs in the Content Project or in the actual code project? From the error, it sounds like it is in the content project.

Comment: @Jaako Wow... Thank you. Turns out there was a duplicate of the original file in the content project area, where all the images are. Much appreciated. How did you realise this?

Comment: @EvanKohilas Well the error was talking about (content) importers, so I just guessed that the file was in the content project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A copy of the file was created and left in the content area of the project where all the images/sounds are. After removing the file, the game executed as per normal. 
*Thanks to jaakko lipsanen*